# Android Studio not recognizing Espresso/Hamcrest static method names without prefacing with the classname

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-testing, android-espresso

I wasn't sure exactly what headline to give this question because I'm not sure what this is technically called. In Android Studio while typing out Espresso tests I noticed that it refuses to accept something like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.someId)).perform(click());
```

and instead will only accept this:

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.someId)).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

even though every example that I've seen online shows the first example as correct code. Why is Android Studio forcing me to preface every ViewMatcher/Espresso/ViewActions/etc. method with the classname even after the imports are included in my class?

To clarify - trying to use the first example shows "cannot resolve method" and using autocomplete on it (which I have to do several times before it will work) invariably autocompletes to the second example. In all the "regular" code for my project autocomplete works correctly and short method names are recognized. I've tried doing a "clean" and "invalidate cache and restart" but no change.

Example of Google doc that shows usage according to the shortened code:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try to check out your Android Studio Preferences for imports. Just go to *Preferences -> Search "imports"*

Here are the settings that I use and I don't have that issue:

[image: imports_1]

[image: imports_2]

Answer (score 0):

What fixed the issue for me: just removed red **withId** in one place. Then just re-entered "withId": after that all the other red withId were replaced with black text color **withId** and now it compiled successfull!